# Format.js not recognized as a template on Heroku (works in development mode)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been struggling to find a way for Heroku to perform Ajax requests in my Rails project. In development mode, my controllers works flawlessly and when an Ajax request is performed, it promptly renders the expected .js.erb file and works as expected.

However, when I'm in production on Heroku, the project throws a missing template error and the page crashes. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue? I'm not sure what code would be helpful to post since the problem seems to be with configuring something on Heroku.

- I've already tried precompiling assets
- The project was built on a Windows machine

Comment: Look at your heroku logs while performing the action in production. Its likely that there is an error that's causing the ajax request to fail, thus not rendering the view (such as forgetting to migrate your db)

Comment: Have a look at the network requests in your browser - are the requests going to the right URL? Do they have the right parameters? What HTTP response code are you getting back? It sounds like you've ruled out frontend problems, so the jQuery and JavaScript tags can probably be removed.